# use setFormula() on a row of cells in Google Script?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, sum

I am trying to sum up a column of data points using the `setFormula()` function. I'm using the formula `=Sum()`.

I'm aiming to add a range of cells inside `=Sum(x:y)` in my spreadsheet.

So far I've tried to use the `get.Range(startRow, startColumn, amountOfRows)`.

But, I'm only getting an error in my spreadSheet #Name. The actual contents of the cell is '=Sum(Range)'

The problem is in my `get.Range()` method. Rather than input a range of cells to sum, it just sticks in a String "Range".

I'd like help using `getRange()` to obtain a valid range of cells that = `=Sum(...)` can sum up. How can I get the proper range of cells (in this case it would be 15,2,3  Or row 15, column 2, 3 total rows down.

```js
function sumOwe3(startRow, startColumn, lastRow){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  //var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  startColumn = startColumn +1;
 //var sum = 0;
  //var end = 0; //end is what Im temp using 
  var fillDownRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, lastRow-startRow);
  Logger.log(fillDownRange);
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, startColumn+2).setFormula("=Sum("+ fillDownRange +")");
  //SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(end, startColumn).setValue(sum);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(lastRow, startColumn+2).setBackground("Yellow");
  var sum = sheet.getRange(lastRow, startColumn+2).getValue();
  Logger.log("The sum is from sumOwe3 is " +sum);
  return sum;

}
```

[image: I need to grab data from column 2 to sum up]

Answer (score 0):

The `getRange()` gets the range for further processing like getting the values from the range.

If you need to get the address of the range to use in the formula, try using `.getA1Notation()`. Ref docs [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getA1Notation()).

Try changing this:

```
  var fillDownRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, lastRow-startRow);
```

to:

```
  var fillDownRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, startColumn, lastRow-startRow).getA1Notation();
```